# TensorFlow linear regresison task - very high loss problem

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, linear-regression

I'm trying to build a linear model on my own yield

```
# Create features 
X = np.array([-7.0, -4.0, -1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 8.0, 11.0, 14.0])

# Create labels
y = np.array([3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 15.0, 18.0, 21.0, 24.0])

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation = "elu", input_shape = [1]),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(loss = "mae",
             optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.01),
             metrics = ["mae"])

model.fit(X, y, epochs = 150)
```

When I train with the above X and y data, the loss value starts from a normal value.

```
experience  salary
0   0   2250
1   1   2750
2   5   8000
3   8   9000
4   4   6900
5   15  20000
6   7   8500
7   3   6000
8   2   3500
9   12  15000
10  10  13000
11  14  18000
12  6   7500
13  11  14500
14  12  14900
15  3   5800
16  2   4000
```

But when I use such a dataset, the initial loss value starts as 800.(same as above model btw)

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your learning rate is significantly high. You should opt for much lower initial learning rates, such as `0.0001` or `0.00001`.

Otherwise you are using 'linear' activation on the last layer (default one) and the correct loss function and metric. Also note that the default `batch_size` in absence of explicit mentioning is `32`.

**UPDATING** : as determined by the author of the question, underfitting was also fundamental to the problem. Adding multiple more layers helped solved the problem.

Comment: I made the learning rate 0.00001 but again the loss value started from 9000

Comment: `X = data.experience`  `y = data.salary` 
I separate the data like this and give it to the model

Comment: What is you change the loss function to MSE?

Comment: In your loss loss = "mse"

Comment: I couldn't find any way, thanks for your help

Comment: Actually I added more dense layers to the model and it worked

Comment: Great. so you were actually suffering from underfitting.

Comment: Probably, thanks for your help <3

Comment: Well, the underfitting was one of the causes, the high learning rate would again have led to instability, I'm sorry I did not offer all the possible causes.

Comment: You are welcome, if you believe it helped you, it would be customary to accept it (since you cannot upvote it). I will correct it/update the answer with the additional suggestion of additional layers if you consider it suitable

Comment: Of course you can. Problem was a underfitting